# how do find the number of rows in a table when the table name is in a variable?

Tags: sql

The following is not working :(

```
Select @CurrentTableName = TableName from @tempTableNames Where ID = @ID  
Select @NumberOfColumns = SELECT count(*) FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = @CurrentTableName
Select @SqlStmt = 'SELECT count(*) FROM ' + @CurrentTableName
Select @NumberOfRwos = exec @SqlStmt
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Declare @Count int
Declare @Sql nvarchar(4000)
Set @Sql = 'Select @Count = Count(*) From ' + Quotename(@CurrentTableName)

exec sp_executesql @SQL, N'@Count int OUTPUT', @Count OUTPUT

Select @Count...
```