# Use a variable for table name

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, variables, sql-server-2000

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how do find the number of rows in a table when the table name is in a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2648280/how-do-find-the-number-of-rows-in-a-table-when-the-table-name-is-in-a-variable)

I need to find tables in a SQL Server database (2000) that contain one value for a column.

I can use the following query to output a list of possible candidate tables containing `my_column`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 'my_column'
```

What I would like to get at, is the following pseudo query with result:

```
select '$TABLE_NAME', count(*) from $TABLE_NAME where my_column = '12345'

table01 1
table02 5
table03 0
table04 3
```

Or more generally formulated: Is it possible to make the FROM-clause variable?

Comment: What *real* version of SQL Server are you using? There's no `2003` version - we have 2000, 2005, 2008, 2008 R2 and 2012 ....

Comment: Thanks, marc_s, the version is 2000, corrected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only way it's possible is by using dynamic SQL:

```
declare @stmt nvarchar(max), @value nvarchar(max)

select @stmt = isnull(@stmt + ' union all ', '') + '
    select ''' + TABLE_NAME +  ''', count(*) from ' +  TABLE_NAME + ' where my_column = @value' 
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where COLUMN_NAME = 'my_column'

select @value = '12345'

exec sp_executesql
    @stmt = @stmt,
    @params = N'@value nvarchar(max)',
    @value = @value
```

**update:**
For SQL 2000 you can use `nvarchar(4000)` If you have really big number of tables, you can use temporary table + cursor:

```
create table #Temp_Results (table_name nvarchar(128), cnt int)
declare @stmt nvarchar(4000), @value nvarchar(128)

declare t_cursor cursor local fast_forward for
    select 
        'select ''' + TABLE_NAME +  ''', count(*) from ' +  TABLE_NAME + ' where id = @value'
    from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    where COLUMN_NAME = 'name'

select @value = 1

open t_cursor
fetch t_cursor into @stmt
while @@fetch_status = 0
begin
    insert into #Temp_Results
    exec sp_executesql
        @stmt = @stmt,
        @params = N'@value nvarchar(128)',
        @value = @value

    fetch t_cursor into @stmt
end

close t_cursor
deallocate t_cursor

select * from #Temp_Results
```

Comment: @AaronBertrand yes it's possible, shouldn't use the only word. But please provide a real answer with code. Will it be more readable then my answer? I doubt it. **update:** oops, sorry, I thought your answer was about foreachtable

Comment: @AaronBertrand nope, I thought your answer for about `sp_MSforeachtable`, so that comment is not for you :). But, anyway, you query is just returning number of rows in tables and it's not possible to pass a value to it, like `my_column = '12345'`

Comment: Thanks, this looks promising. 2000 apparently does not support max. And the result is not complete. Will try to understand what you are doing, and where this wrong result comes from.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - Are you saying there is another option than dynamic sql? If so, can you elaborate? I would love to know of an alternative.

Comment: @Leigh I was confused about `column_name = 'my column'` and `my column = '12345'` - I thought it was about counting the rows in the whole table (which you can do with relative accuracy without dynamic SQL), but it seems to be an effort to count a subset.'

Comment: @AaronBertrand - Gotcha. I just did not want to miss learning a new trick (if there was one).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the sp_MSforeachtable undocumented stored procedure to make the FROM clause variable.Here is an article that shows how to use it: [sp_msForEachTable examples](http://www.sqlservercurry.com/2009/04/8-common-uses-of-undocumented-stored.html)

Comment: The OP only wants to execute against tables that contain a certain column, not all tables. I'm not sure that your answer really helps without an example that actually does that.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question, you want a list of tables containing a given column name and a record count from each table, yes?  If so

```
select o.name as "Table Name", i.rowcnt as "Rows"
from sysobjects o
inner join sysindexes i on o.id = i.id
where i.indid in (0,1)
and o.id in
    (select distinct id from syscolumns where name = 'My_Column')
order by o.name
```

Requires that you have ability to query system tables.

Comment: Almost. He also wants to search that column for a specific value ie number rows where column `x` contains value `y`