# SQL use a variable as TABLE NAME in a FROM

Tags: sql-server

We install our database(s) to different customers and the name can change depending on the deployment.
What I need to know is if you can use a variable as a table name.
The database we are in is ****_x and we need to access ****_m.
This code is part of a function.
I need the @metadb variable to be the table name - Maybe using dynamic SQL with
sp_executesql. I am just learning so take it easy on me.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[datAddSp] (
@cal NCHAR(30) -- calendar to use to non-working days
,@bDays INT -- number of business days to add or subtract
,@d DATETIME 
    )

RETURNS DATETIME
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @nDate DATETIME -- the working date
,@addsub INT -- factor for adding or subtracting
,@metadb sysname

SET @metadb = db_name()
SET @metadb = REPLACE (@metadb,'_x','_m')
SET @metadb = CONCAT (@metadb,'.dbo.md_calendar_day')
SET @ndate = @d

 IF @bdays > 0
SET @addsub = 1
ELSE
SET @addsub = -1

IF @cal = '                              ' OR @cal IS NULL
SET @cal = 'CA_ON'
WHILE @bdays <> 0 -- Keep adding/subtracting a day until @bdays becomes 0
BEGIN
SELECT @ndate = dateadd(day, 1 * @addsub, @ndate) -- increase or decrease    @ndate

SELECT @bdays = CASE 
WHEN (@@datefirst + datepart(weekday, @ndate)) % 7 IN (0, 1) -- ignore if it is Sat or Sunday 
THEN @bdays
WHEN ( SELECT 1
FROM @metadb -- **THIS IS WHAT I NEED** (same for below) this table holds the holidays
WHERE mast_trunkibis_m.dbo.md_calendar_day.calendar_code = @cal AND  mast_trunkibis_m.dbo.md_calendar_day.calendar_date = @nDate AND mast_trunkibis_m.dbo.md_calendar_day.is_work_day = 0
 ) IS NOT NULL -- ignore if it is in the holiday table
 THEN @bdays
 ELSE @bdays - 1 * @addsub -- incr or decr @ndate
 END
 END
 RETURN @nDate
 END
 GO
```

Comment: You can accomplish this by creating your queries using concatenated strings, but that is not a very safe/clean approach. It would probably be better to create identical table structures in schemas for each customer.

Comment: Indeed, keep the schema the same. There is no good reason to have different table names for different client installations. If you are stuck with legacy code/database, dynamic SQL is your only option. Be sure to escape strings properly if you use dynamic SQL.

Comment: Can't you use a "canonical" name in your function and create a synonym for your specific customers?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use a variable for table name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13630347/use-a-variable-for-table-name)

Comment: WHY does the name have to be different for each customer? You said "install our database(s) TO different customers" which sounds like the database is at their site. No need to have different names. If you are running all the customer databases locally (IE, your company has all the databases on your server), you could use SCHEMA to keep them separate rather than changing the database name.

Comment: It's more or less to keep track of it by customer. It doesn't work very well if all of the names are the same.

Comment: @HarryValters sure it does, you differentiate the customers by their schema name. For instance, if you have companies ABC and DEF you would access a table named `products` for company ABC by: `[database].ABC.products` and for DEF it would similarly be: `[database].DEF.products`. There is no reason to have the companies name in the tablename. You can set the default schema to use as part of the connection string so all the queries would actually only reference `products`.

Comment: There are two different databases - One for tables with customer data and one database with metadata tables. I need to open the meta table in a function and the database name can not be hard coded with a certain name. The *_x is customer the *_m is metadata.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this, if you aren't stuck with existing structures is to keep all of the table structures and names the same, simply create a schema for each customer and build out the tables in the schema. For example, if you have the companies: `Global Trucking` and `Super Store` you would create a schema for each of those companies: `GlobalTrucking` and `SuperStore` are now your schemas.

Supposing you have `products` and `payments` tables for a quick example. You would create those tables in each schema so you end up with something that looks like this:

```
GlobalTrucking.products
GlobalTrucking.payments
```

and

```
SuperStore.products
SuperStore.payments
```

Then in the application layer, you specify the default schema name to use in the connection string for queries using that connection. The web site or application for Global Trucking has the schema set to `GlobalTrucking` and any query like: `SELECT * FROM products;` would actually automatically be `SELECT * FROM GlobalTrucking.products;` when executed using that connection.

This way you always know where to look in your tables, and each customer is in their own segregated space, with the proper user permissions they will never be able to accidentally access another customers data, and everything is just easier to navigate.

Here is a sample of what your schema/user/table creation script would look like (this may not be 100% correct, I just pecked this out for a quick example, and I should mention that this is the Oracle way, but SQL Server should be similar):

```
CREATE USER &SCHEMA_NAME IDENTIFIED BY temppasswd1;
CREATE SCHEMA AUTHORIZATION &SCHEMA_NAME
CREATE TABLE "&SCHEMA_NAME".products
(
    ProductId           NUMBER,
    Description         VARCHAR2(50),
    Price               NUMBER(10, 2),
    NumberInStock       NUMBER,
    Enabled             VARCHAR2(1)
)
CREATE TABLE "&SCHEMA_NAME".payments
(
    PaymentId           NUMBER,
    Amount              NUMBER(10, 2),
    CardType            VARCHAR2(2),
    CardNumber          VARCHAR2(15),
    CardExpire          DATE,
    PaymentTimeStamp    TIMESTAMP,
    ApprovalCode        VARCHAR2(25)
)
GRANT SELECT ON "&SCHEMA_NAME".products TO &SCHEMA_NAME
GRANT SELECT ON "&SCHEMA_NAME".payments TO &SCHEMA_NAME
;
```

However, with something like the above, you only have 1 script that you need to keep updated for automation of adding new customers. When you run this, the `&SCHEMA_NAME` variable will be populated with whatever you choose for the new customer's username/schemaname, and an identical table structure is created every time.